# Can't connect to MySQL container from Golang container

Tags: mysql, docker, go

I have 2 containers: a simple golang program and mysql.
I can start both but the golang application can not connect to mysql. I receive **Connection Refused**.

If I `docker exec` into the **mysql** container and try to connect locally with `mysql -u root -p` all works well.

If on the the host I try to connect to the container with `mysql -h 0.0.0.0 -P 10000 -u root -p` all works well.

I added `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'` in `docker-compose` and `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` into `mysqld.cnf` but still not working.

What I'm doing wrong?

**docker-compose**

```yml
    version: '3'
    services:
      web:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "8081:8081" # http
          - "443:443" # https
        links:
          - db_private
        volumes:
         - ../../../../.:/go
      db_private:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
          MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        ports:
          - '10000:3306'
        expose:
          - '3306'
        volumes:
          - ./mysql-entry-point.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          - private-db:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./mysqld.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    # Names our volume
    volumes:
      private-db:
```

**Web container Dockerfile**

```
    FROM golang:alpine
    RUN mkdir /app
    ADD . /app/
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git openssh
    
    RUN go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm
    RUN go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql
    RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
    RUN go get github.com/gin-contrib/cors
    
    
    RUN go build -o main .
    RUN adduser -S -D -H -h /app appuser
    USER appuser
    CMD ["./main"]
```

**Golang file**

```golang
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
        _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
        "net/http"
        "time"
    )
    
    var db *gorm.DB
    
    type (
        FooModel struct {
            Id        int64 `gorm:"primary_key"`
            name      string
        }
    )
    
    func init() {
        //open a db connection
        var err error
        db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "user:pwd@(0.0.0.0:10000)/myDB?charset=utf8&parseTime=true")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            panic("failed to connect database")
        }
        //Migrate the schema
        db.AutoMigrate(&FooModel{})
    
        db.LogMode(true)
    }
    
    // main inits routes
    func main() {
    
        router := gin.Default()
    
        router.GET("/getExample", getExample)
        
        router.Run("0.0.0.0:8081")
    }
    
    
    func getExample(c *gin.Context) {
    
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": http.StatusOK, "data": "bye"})
    }
```

**I copy the `mysqld.cnf` in the container with this**

```
    [mysqld]
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
    #log-error  = /var/log/mysql/error.log
    # By default we only accept connections from localhost
    #bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
    bind-address   = 0.0.0.0
    # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
    symbolic-links=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your web app is running in a container, which means the address 0.0.0.0 is the container itself, not the host it is running on. Try connecting the db using `db_private` name instead of the address 0.0.0.0.

Comment: I changed `db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "user:pwd@(0.0.0.0:10000)/myDB?charset=utf8&parseTime=true")' to 'db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "user:pwd@(db_private:10000)/myDB?charset=utf8&parseTime=true")' but I still receive 'dial tcp 0.0.0.0:10000: connect: connection refused'

Comment: Your code is still trying to connect to 0.0.0.0. Maybe something went wrong during image build? You're not running the changed program.

Comment: I'm doing docker system prune --volumes and then docker-compose build, am I missing something?

Comment: One more thing: try db_private:3306, because that's the port open on the container. It is published as 10000 on the host.

Answer (score 1):

`0.0.0.0` is not your container's IP address.  It's a special address meaning "all available interfaces".

You are connecting from your Host to the Container with `0.0.0.0` because they do share an interface because you exposed the ports in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

If your application is always going to live in a container, and your database is always going to live in a container, Docker provides a method for you to connect one to the other.

`db_private`, the service name, can be found from your `web` (or golang) container.

This will always work, because Docker has an internal DNS server which your containers can use, no matter which IP address your containers have.

```
host> docker-compose up -d
host> docker-compose exec web /bin/sh
 web$ ping db_private
```

Yes, you always want to use `0.0.0.0` as bind interfaces within containers because you never know WHICH IP address you will get, so that's like a shortcut to say "all".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, instead use `db_private` of Docker host, I get my local IP by running:

`ipconfig getifaddr en0` => 172.16.4.227

Then I use this IP in my gorm SQL connection:

```
db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "user:pwd@(172.16.4.227:10000)/myDB?charset=utf8&parseTime=true")
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve the problem in `just 3 steps`:

1. Change your `ports` from `10000:3306` to `3306:3306` in the `docker-compose` file.
2. Change `0.0.0.0:10000` to `db_private:3306` in the `Golang file`.
3. There is no need to prune containers and images. Run the following command instead:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful for someone! I had the same issue and spent 5 hours to figure out the issue.
In my case, I was using "sqlc" for golang and also wanted to pass connection string via compose file.

[image]

But I got error like access denied to 'root'@'x.x.x.x' when I tried to call api by postman. Long story short, I remove double quotation marks form DB_SOURCE, and it worked!

```
- DB_SOURCE=root:my-secret-pw@tcp(mysql:3306)/simple_bank?parseTime=true&autocommit=true
```